# Doctrine2 custom type array hydration

Tags: doctrine-orm

I included the `knplabs/doctrine-behaviors` module in my ZF2 project to get the geocodable behavior. It adds a custom mapping type `point` which stores the values of lat and lng in a mysql point column.

The problem is, that the value of the entity field does not get hydrated in the result set, if I choose the array hydration mode. The result is an object and should be an array.

Is there a way to set a custom hydration strategie for a custom field type or anything else?

**Current result:**

```
array(1) { 
    ["id"]=> int(269)
    ["address"]=> array(4) {
        ["id"]=> int(269)
        ["street"]=> string(14) "Rathausplatz 1" 
        ["location"]=> object(Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\ORM\Geocodable\Type\Point)#1504 (2) { 
            ["latitude":"Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\ORM\Geocodable\Type\Point":private]=> float(50.938212)
            ["longitude":"Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\ORM\Geocodable\Type\Point":private]=> float(6.959035) 
        }
    }
}
```

**Wanted result:**

```
array(1) { 
    ["id"]=> int(269)
    ["address"]=> array(4) {
        ["id"]=> int(269)
        ["street"]=> string(14) "Rathausplatz 1" 
        ["location"]=> array(2) { 
            ["latitude"]=> float(50.938212)
            ["longitude"] => float(6.959035) 
        }
    }
}
```